# How to correctly import whitewater particles from fluid simulation (FLIP fluids)?

Tags: import, fluid-simulation, instances, point-clouds, alembic

I exported a FLIP fluids simulation to Alembic (.abc) and imported it into another blend file.

The fluid itself works fine however the whitewater particles are not visible.

According to the docs, I have to "instance the particles" onto the fluid.

I looked at Blender documentation and put the fluid as the parent of the white water particle like this:

[image: particles child to fluid]

Then in the object properties I enabled instancing to "Vertices" and the particles are not appearing where they should be (on the fluid).

[image]

As you can see the particles are not in their correct position. How do I fix this?

Comment: The instancing on vertices doesn't work with particles - because particles are not vertices. What is meant is the regular instancing which you normally do with particle simulations when you want to see them in render: go to _Particle Properties_ > _Render_ > _Render As_ and choose _Object_ instead of _Halo_, then further down choose the object you want to instance on the particles like e.g. an icosphere.

Comment: But that is how you get particles before Alembic export. So I have no idea how this actually works... You cannot instance particles itself on the fluid's vertices, you have to instance objects. And if you would instance objects on the vertices of the fluid, they would be distributed on the mesh of the fluid, not where the whitewater particles are. But when you say "according to the docs": which docs? What part in "the docs"? I don't have those docs so I cannot read in which context this is written, maybe there's more to it that explains what exactly you are supposed to do.

Comment: The FLIP Fluids addon documentation topic can be found here: https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Alembic-Export-Support#rendering-alembic-whitewater

I have updated the documentation to be more clear on the setup and to add screenshots .

Answer (score 2):

The FLIP Fluids addon documentation for how to render Alembic whitewater using instancing or point clouds can be found here: [Alembic Export Support > Rendering Alembic Whitewater](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Alembic-Export-Support#rendering-alembic-whitewater)

#### Rendering Using Instancing

To set up instancing manually for the FLIP Fluids whitewater meshes:

1. Create a mesh object to represent the particle, such as an icosphere.
2. Set the particle object's parent as the whitewater mesh (whitewater_foam, whitewater_bubble, whitewater_spray, whitewater_dust).
3. Set the instancing mode on the whitewater mesh to *Vertices*.

[image]

#### Rendering Using Point Clouds

Alternatively, the whitewater meshes can be converted to Point Cloud objects in Blender 3.1 or later. Point clouds are much more efficient for rendering speed and resource usage.

This can be done by using the *[Mesh to Points geometry node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/mesh_to_points.html)*:

[image]

Comment: Great tips about point clouds, thank you!

Comment: What about particle foam? is it the same? do we need to "make instances real" or "make particle instances to objects", and from there we just "export"?