# Exporting mesh to Keyshot

Tags: export

I am new to Blender so hopefully this is a simple question. I used particles to create a grass like structure and then converted the particles to a mesh in Blender. But no matter what I export the mesh as, I can't get Keyshot to open it. I have brought meshes in from Keyshot before so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I think maybe this has a similar answer to what you are looking for <https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285505/how-to-correctly-import-whitewater-particles-from-fluid-simulation-flip-fluids>